# Unable to call the function to assign value to variable in constructor pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign value to variable(chartWidth) by calling the method calculateChartWidth().

But I am facing the error that calculateChartWidth is not a defined function.

```
var ForceSimulationChart = function(){
    this.width = document.querySelector("svg").clientWidth;
    this.height = document.querySelector("svg").clientHeight;

    this.margin = {top:5, left:5, bottom:5, right:5 };

    //this.chartWidth = this.width - (this.margin.left+this.margin.right);
    //this.chartHeight = this.height - (this.margin.top+this.margin.bottom);

    this.chartWidth = this.calculateChartWidth();
    this.chartHeight = this.calculateChartHeight();

    this.svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg");   
    this.chartLayer = this.svg.append("g").classed("chartLayer", true);

    this.calculateChartWidth = function(){
        return this.width - (this.margin.left+this.margin.right);
    }

    this.calculateChartHeight = function(){
        return this.Height - (this.margin.top+this.margin,bottom);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there an svg in the document? what happens when you call - document.querySelector("svg")

Comment: How are you calling `calculateChartWidth`?

Comment: If you assign your function definition to a variable then it is not hoisted which means not available to things calling it from above its definition. See here: http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/variable-and-function-hoisting.html

Answer (score 1):

Your function isn't defined when you call it, from what I can see. You need to declare and define your function before your call `this.chartWidth = calculateChartWidth();`

Essentially, what you have is:

```
var dog = callUndefinedFunction();

var callUndefinedFunction = function() { 
    // ...
```

When what you need is:

```
var callUndefinedFunction = function() { 
    // ...
};

var dog = callDefinedFunction();
```

Looking at the code first code snippet (equivalent to what you have), you are - at the time of calling `callUndefinedFunction` - accessing an undefined variable: you haven't declared it or assigned a definition to it.

By moving the declaration of the variable and it's definition above the call (the second code block), you avoid this problem.

#### But Your Code Still Fails

I've gone back and modified your initial question - removing extraneous code; however, you will encounter the same problem with other code in your example, elsewhere, as you repeat this same problem in your call to `calculateChartHeight`.

`calculateChartWidth` failed because it was the first line to break in your code.

The rest will fail once that is resolved.

#### But You Like Your Ordering

Well, if you don't want to move a bunch of "stuff", you can read about [hoisting](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) in the context of Javascript. Functions are "hoisted" in Javascript differently than variables, so pay attention to that distinction.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor functions are used to create instances of objects. They typically take arguments which are assigned as properties. See MDN's [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

```
// Object Constructor Functions
function Credential(id, username, password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

//push object to credentials array
try {
    credentials.push(new Credential(id, username, password));
}
catch (e) {
    console.log('Error: Failed Adding Credential ' + id + '.');
    return;
}
```